# Can this assignment be made simpler by destructuring?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm still trying to learn all the way to destructure. I know enough to know that there might be a way to write this more concisely. Is there?

```
      this.props.setStateObjects({
        data:     data.reservation_data.data,
        included: data.reservation_data.included
      })
```

Edit:

As per @Sung M Kim's request below, this is the context:

```
    $.ajax({
    })
    .done( ( data ) => {
      this.props.setStateObjects({
        data:     data.reservation_data.data,
        included: data.reservation_data.included
      })
    })
```

Comment: Can you provide more context as how `data.*` object is passed? It might provide more insight on how to make it more readable.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply destructuring to `data` to pluck out `reservation_data`, then pluck out `data` and `included` fields from `reservation_data`. Then you can set those in state with the shorthand object key value notation like so

```
const { reservation_data: { data: dataToSet, included } } = data
```

or less destructured

```
const { data: dataToSet, included } = data
```

then set it in state

```
this.props.setStateObjects({
  data: dataToSet,
  included
})
```

Comment: And, how is this simpler/better/more concise?

Comment: it uses destructuring so it's automatically more readable and has less complex assignments. if you want to make it even simpler you can put this.props.setState in one line, but imo that's for a cost of readability

Comment: That's a matter of opinion.  It's more lines of code and seems less concise and less obvious to me (creating multiple temporary variables in the current scope when the original did not).  More work for the interpreter and the garbage collector.  The only plus I see is that it removes one instance of typing `data.reservation_data`.  But, that could be done with an intermediate variable too if that was really a problem worth solving.

Comment: @jfriend00 if you destructure you are creating variables to destructure into, thats how it works. The OP asked a question about how to make it more concise and use destructuring. Whats your issue with the answer?

Comment: Already stated.  I don't think this is more concise or simpler.  That's a matter of opinion and I've stated my opinion.  You can have a different opinion.  FYI, IMO your recent edit makes it less simple than it was.   I'm commenting to share my opinion.

Comment: Again, the OP **asked** for a way to use destructuring. And the answer provided is a fairly standard / accepted practice for destructuring. If you dont like it thats fine, but that doesn't mean this answer is bad or invalid in any way. Destructuring has been standard for a long time now, if you find it hard to read maybe use it more :)

Comment: If the exercise is to rewrite the OP's code with destructuring, you win.  If the exercise is to make the code simpler or more concise, I don't think you did that.  Just my opinion.

Comment: Sure, agreed. Just saying thats what the specific ask was :)

Comment: I think the real exercise here is destructuring cleanly while avoiding the generic issue of overwriting the object itself since it has the same name as a parameter you want. For the OP's case specifically this is good but obviously if there's any more to it or you want something extendable this isn't great

Comment: Just for the record, what I was trying to ask for was IF I could make my code more simple/concise with destructuring. I'm appreciating everyone's opinions. I liked @PiekarskiD 's original answer. It seemed equally clear to me, but not necessarily simpler. Maybe equally concise as mine. I also like @ jfriend's points about the resource allocation tradeoffs...

Answer (score 1):

Using the spread operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

```
let pickedParameters = (({ data, included }) => ({ data, included }))(data.reservation_data);

this.props.setStateObjects({...pickedParameters});
```

Alternatively to get data and included you can use this format to avoid the function, still repetitive and ugly though:

```
let pickedParams = {};
({data: pickedParams.data, included: pickedParams.included} = data.reservation_data);
```

Comment: This assumes that 'data' and 'included' are the only attributes in reservation data. I think. But there are more, and I don't want them added.

Comment: Okay i edited it to add destructuring to pick the ones you want

Comment: @pixelearth while this does work, please never write code like that lol

Comment: @Jayce444 it's more concise than writing a filter but obviously there are alternatives . I'll throw another one in the edits but it doesn't make the arrow function for destructuring not standard

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using a function to do this... There are times where you may need to like if its a really complicated  set of data you are destructuring and or if you need to do any transformations. But for this specific use case its a little heavy and or not as concise.

Comment: And requires much more cognitive overhead.